# Magento add javascript before default javascript

Tags: magento, header

I'm currently developing a custom module for admin and I would like to add a custom javascript before default ones.
I tried to use :

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>path/to/javascript.js</name><params/><if/></action>
```

But this line add javascript after default like prototype.js, window.js...
Is there a way to add mine before ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout` `page.xml` (if you are using default theme otherwise go to `yourtheme\default\layout`) and you js here

```
    <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addJs">
               <script>yourjs/yourjs.js</script>
           </action>

            <action method="addJs">
               <script>prototype/prototype.js</script>
           </action>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to re-order of the JavaScript files loaded in the admin, then in your layout xml handle, you will need to remove all of the script files, then add yours and then re-add them again. Please note that your js file should be in the js folder, not the skin one.

```
<!-- Remove the added ones -->
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>prototype/window.js</name></action>
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/builder.js</name></action>
... 
<!-- Add yours -->
<action method="addJs"><script>path/to/javascript.js</script></action>
<!-- Add the removed ones after -->
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/window.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
...
```